# if elseif statement in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

Both if and elseif statement are working at the same time.

```
  while($answerResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($answers))
  {
    if($reportResult != 0 && $this->CheckAnswer($questionId,$answerResult['id'],$reportResult))
    {
       echo '<input type="radio" name="question['.$questionId.']" value="'.$answerResult['id'].'" checked/>'.$answerResult['name'].'aaa&nbsp;&nbsp';
    }
    elseif($sampleResult != 0 && $this->CheckAnswer($questionId,$answerResult['id'],$sampleResult))
    {
       echo '<input type="radio" name="question['.$questionId.']" value="'.$answerResult['id'].'" checked/>'.$answerResult['name'].'hee&nbsp;&nbsp';
    }
    else
    {
       echo '<input type="radio" name="question['.$questionId.']" value="'.$answerResult['id'].'" />'.$answerResult['name'].'&nbsp;&nbsp';
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to do if my first statement is true then don't look other conditions but if my first condition is false then check elseif condition.

However, my elseif condition is working even though first if condition is true.

I put 'hee' and 'aaa' at the end of the 'echos' to see which one is printing.

The result:

First, if statement is working and printing with 'aaa' then looking at the elseif statement and checked this and print 'hee'.

So, I don't know what i am missing and can't find any solution, Is there any suggestion?

Comment: You should try a output at the top of your while loop. I bet there a multiple rows.

Comment: Are you sure that 'aaa' and 'hee' are printed in the same iteration of the `while` loop?

Comment: as i understood, you said at the second or different iteration of the while loop can change the result, if so i should change all structure

Comment: just add  $i @ the end of all statement and @ the end of while just add i++; and check it once more still there is issue

Comment: is it allowed to put screenshot of my result here? i didn't see in faq

Comment: @AkhilrajNS this is the result after adding $i http://e1212.hizliresim.com/14/7/gnkub.jpg only 'aaa' values should be checked

Answer (score 3):

The `if`, `elseif`, and `else` in one statement are exclusive, so this shouldn't happen.

The whole statement is in a while loop ... are you sure it's not the `if` being executed in the first iteration and the `elseif` being executed in the second iteration?

Comment: you can be right so i should check while statement first, thanks.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` always fetches one row from the database query result - I suppose the query you're issuing there has more result rows, otherwise there would be no use for a `while` loop

Comment: my query is "SELECT * FROM answer" and in my answer table i have: "id,name" : "1,yes", "2,no", "3,na"

Comment: Well that sounds lile one condition is true for `(1, yes)` and the other one for `(2, no)` (for example). With that query the `while` should loop 3 times

Comment: so second iteration can be true for elseif condition and this can change result although first iteration is true for if condition.

Comment: yes. in the first iteration, `$answerResult` contains something different than in the second or third iteration